# Mysql query noobie assistance

Tags: mysql

Hello i hired a coder to do most my sites work. But i would like to be able to  do some basic things i tried to use mysql query builder but still cant get the  concept lol.  so its probably really basic but i have two tables.

```
$sql  = "SELECT distinct count(title) FROM #cookingbooks ";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$cooking= $db->loadResult();
//var_dump($cooking);die;


$sql  = "SELECT distinct count(title) FROM #historybooks ";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$history= $db->loadResult();
//var_dump($history);die;
```

now either one of them will get me a count of the records,  but this is where i struggle.  How can i  make one query to count the records from both tables and give me the total from both  tables ? as one   So instead of having 12,000 books for cooking.  and 38,000 for history. i would just get 50,000 as my result

Comment: What prevents you from adding the numbers up in php?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT serves no purpose here.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM table_a UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_b) n;`

Comment: i am not a coder. i hired a coder to create  the existing code.  i could look into that though. figured it had to be a query

Comment: thanks strawberry  i will try that. i tried join but was going in circles and not getting correct results

Comment: i got this result when ran in phpmyadmin     1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that, but you will still need multiple queries to do that. It may be simpler to add a the 2 numbers together in php, but here you go:

```
select (SELECT count(title) FROM #cookingbooks)
     + (SELECT count(title) FROM #historybooks) as total_books
```

You may want to reconsider yor database structure and have a single `books` table with a type field, where the type field can identify if the book is about history or cooking. Or have a more complex tagging system by adding a `tags` and a `tag_of_books` table, where a single book can belong to multiple categories. E.g. a book called "History of Cooking" can belong to both categories.